# Add html tags inside a replace method of js(no Jquery)

Tags: javascript

I'm using the replace method of js to replace a value to style it differently.

```
style() {
   var name = "StackoverFlow";
   var value = "Flow";
   var regex = new RegExp("(" + value + ")", "gi");
   return "<span>"+name.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>")+"</span>"; //replacing the value "Flow" with bold.
}
```

but instead it returns: `Stackover<strong>Flow</strong>`.
how can i parse it using the html() instead of plain text and render: Stackover**Flow**

Comment: What is the method you use to check the output?

Comment: That's what your code is supposed to return, a plain string. How it appears on a page, depends on how you're using the return value. Can you please show that?

Comment: So you want to see bold text in console.log? That sadly won't happen. You need to put this on the page to get rendered properly. You can use something like `document.getElementById("idOfADiv").innerHtml=style();` where `idOfADiv` is the id of a `<div>` element. (of course others will do but that seems the simplest.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are setting the return value of the function to the document. However, the function I do believe you are looking for is: `element.innerHTML`.

Example

```
var element = document.getElementById('myelement');

element.innerHTML = "stack<strong>flow</strong>" //outputs flow in bold text.
```

Suggestion

```
<!-- in html -->
<p id="your_element_id"></p>
```

.

```
//js
var element = document.getElementById('your_element_id');
element.innerHTML = style();

function style() {
   var name = "StackoverFlow";
   var value = "Flow";
   var regex = new RegExp("(" + value + ")", "gi");
   return "<span>"+name.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>")+"</span>";
}
```